# Bokeh twin axes with DataRange1d not well scaling

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

I want to plot some data on a plot with twin axes, I found in documentation an [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#twin-axes), but I need dynamic ranges (DataRange1d) because my data will be changing during visualization and I don't know in advance what it will be.

My problem: both y ranges have the same scaling, and are locked together : I can't zoom out a range only.

```
from numpy import pi, arange, sin, linspace
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, DataRange1d
from bokeh.models import Plot, Title, PanTool, WheelZoomTool
from bokeh.models import Circle, ColumnDataSource

# get some data
x = arange(-2*pi, 2*pi, 0.1)
y = sin(x)
y2 = linspace(0, 100, len(y))

# configure plot
p = Plot(title = Title(text="Titre"), x_range = DataRange1d(), y_range = DataRange1d())
p.add_tools(PanTool(), WheelZoomTool())
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(), "below")
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(), "left")

# add extra y range
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": DataRange1d()}
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo"), 'right')

# plot using both axes
cds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, y2=y2))
c1 = Circle(x="x", y="y", line_color="red", fill_color="red")
p.add_glyph(cds, c1)
c2 = Circle(x="x", y="y2", line_color="blue", fill_color="blue")
p.add_glyph(cds, c2, y_range_name="foo")

show(p)
```

[image: bokeh plot]

Comment: does the scaling stay locked when you hover and scroll directly over one of the axis?

Comment: Yes, if I wheel-zoom on one y-axis, both y-axis are zooming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `DataRange1d` computes its start and end using all renderers. But you can specify which renderers to use:

```
[...]

c1 = Circle(x="x", y="y", line_color="red", fill_color="red")
c1_renderer = p.add_glyph(cds, c1)
p.y_range.renderers = [c1_renderer]

c2 = Circle(x="x", y="y2", line_color="blue", fill_color="blue")
c2_renderer = p.add_glyph(cds, c2, y_range_name="foo")
p.extra_y_ranges['foo'].renderers = [c2_renderer]

[...]
```

Comment: This "renderers" parameters escape my attention, thank you, you made my day !

Comment: I have [scaling problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830962/bokeh-twin-axes-not-scaling-well-when-dynamic-adding-curves) when trying to add dynamically glyph to plot, any ideas ?

Comment: @Louc Nothing off the top of my head, sorry.